# wp_enqueue_scripts does not render my scripts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

here is my code in the functions.php file:

```
function load_script() { wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main/js', false, null, true); };
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script');
```

The directory is correct and the script renders properly if I insert a  tag directly in the php with the src set to get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js'.

I have tried a few solutions from previous related questions here and have had no luck. At this point I am tempted to go with what works but I would love to go about doing this the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First of all, I have seen that, there is a syntax error into your code.
`;` after function's closing bracket.
**2.** And also i have sen that you have used `false` at place of depth parameter of `wp_enque_scripts`.
**3.** Also I have seen that your file name is /js/main/js
But this wrong. The js file name should be file_name.js
so the correct code is

```
function load_script() { 
wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main/file_name.js', array(), null, true); 

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script');
```

Try the code , then let me know the result

Comment: Did not work actually, I forgot I hardcoded the JS scripts. Also, I reference main.js and they typo is in the question and not the code.

Comment: @user7023819, if there is typo in your question, then you should to fix it by editing the question

Answer (score 0):

File name is missing. It could be:

```
function load_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main/js/main.js', array(), false, false);
};
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_script');
```